# is there any way to implement youtube like feature just to show empty templates before data loads in angular?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add the feature in my application to render empty templates before the data loads once the data loads i am showing the cards filled with data in  angular5

Comment: What would you need would be something like this?
https://codepen.io/u3u/pen/MprVZP
Could you be more specific, please?

Comment: yes like this only .In my project we are using cards to display data and that cards are using at many places.That card itself is component which we are using at different places.so i want it to show the skeleton till the data loads from the server once the data loads actual cards should show .